# Firebase hosting custom headers not working

Tags: firebase, http-headers, firebase-hosting

I deploy a static site on firebase hosting with some header configuarations.
But I some of my headers doesn't appear after the site deployed.

I tried change the value of `Cache-Control` header and it works.
But `X-Frame-Options`,`Content-Security-Policy`,`X-Content-Type-Options` doesn't.

firebase.json:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        "headers": [
            {
                "source": "**/*.@(html)",
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "key": "Cache-Control",
                        "value": "max-age=3600"
                    },
                        {
                        "key": "X-Frame-Options",
                        "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
                        "value":
                            "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg)",
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "key": "Cache-Control",
                        "value": "max-age=2592000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "**/*.@(js|css)",
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "key": "Cache-Control",
                        "value": "max-age=2592000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "**/*",
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
                        "value": "nosniff"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Actual response header I get:

[image: actual response header]

Comment: Does the current request in your example end in `.html`? Also note that CSP headers are [not configurable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-headers) on Firebase Hosting.

Comment: I am having the same issue, one year later. I am not even able to change `Cache-Control`, though. I would like to set that and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. I am doing exactly what they say on [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) (well, except for the JavaScript comments in a `.json` file, that does not look right).

Comment: Same here, it's 2020 and I have the same issues. I can't change any of the headers. They are not mentioning anything about it in the documentation..

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No solutions so far?

Comment: Still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

After deploy, make sure to clear your browser's cache or use incognito mode. That's what happened to me, my custom headers were not showing because Chrome cached previously deployed version