# Why can't Clarifai validate model output request with API key generated in the Clarifai Portal or with the Personal Access token?

Tags: node.js, firebase, authorization, malformed, clarifai

**Update**

I'm able to get my original code, and the suggestions as well working when running it in isolation. However, what I need to do is call it from within a Firebase `onRequest` or `onCall` function. When this code gets wrapped by these, the malformed headers and request for authorization are still an issue. We use many other APIs this way so it's puzzling why the Clarifiai API is having these issues. Any suggestions on using it with Firebase?

**Original**

New to Clarifai and having some authentication issues while attempting to retrieve model outputs from the Food Model.

I've tried two different keys:

- API key generated from an app I created in the Portal
- API key - the Personal Access Token I generated for myself

In both cases I encounter an `Empty or malformed authorization header` response.

```
{
   "status":{
      "code":11102,
      "description":"Invalid request",
      "details":"Empty or malformed authorization header. Please provide an API key or session token.",
      "req_id":"xyzreasdfasdfasdfasdfasf"
   },
   "outputs":[
      
   ]
}
```

I've following the following articles to piece together this code. This is running in a Node 10 environment.

- [Initialization](https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/api-overview/api-clients#client-installation-instructions)
- [Food Model](https://www.clarifai.com/models/food)
- [Prediction](https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images)

```
  const { ClarifaiStub } = require('clarifai-nodejs-grpc');
  const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
  const stub = ClarifaiStub.json();
  const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
  metadata.set("authorization", "Key xyzKey");

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stub.PostModelOutputs(
      {
        model_id: 'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7',
        inputs: [{ data: { image: { url: 'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg' } } }],
      },
      metadata,
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(`ERROR: ${err}`);
        }

        resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide any error message in the networking/console that you see?  Might help diagnose what is getting affected by firebase.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** There was an issue in versions prior to 7.0.2 where, if you had another library using `@grpc/grpc-js` with a different version, the `grpc.Metadata` object wasn't necessarily constructed from the library version that `clarifai-grpc-nodejs` was using.

To fix the issue, update the `clarifai-grpc-nodejs` library, and require the `grpc` object like this:

```js
const {ClarifaiStub, grpc} = require("clarifai-nodejs-grpc");
```

Previously, the `grpc` object was imported directly from `@grpc/grpc-js`, which was the source of the problem.

---

There are two ways of authenticating to the Clarifai API:

- with an API key, which is application-specific, meaning that an API key is attached to an application and can only do operations inside that application,
- with a Personal Access Token (PAT), which is user-specific, which means you can assess / manipulate / do operations on all the applications the user owns / has access to (and also create/update/delete applications themselves).

When using a PAT, you have to specify, in your request data, which  application you are targeting. With an API key this is not needed.

I've tested your example (using Node 12, though it should work in 10 as well) with a valid API key and it works fina (after putting it into an async function). Here's a full runnable example (replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with your valid API key).

```
function predict() {
  const { ClarifaiStub } = require('clarifai-nodejs-grpc');
  const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
  const stub = ClarifaiStub.json();
  const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
  metadata.set("authorization", "Key YOUR_API_KEY");

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stub.PostModelOutputs(
      {   
        model_id: 'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7',
        inputs: [{ data: { image: { url: 'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg' } } }], 
      },  
      metadata,
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(`ERROR: ${err}`);
        }

        resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
      }   
    );  
  }); 
}

async function main() {
    const response = await predict();
    console.log(response);
}

main();
```

If you want to use a PAT in the above example, two things must change. Firstly, replace the API key with a PAT:

```
...
metadata.set("authorization", "Key YOUR_PAT");
...
```

To the method request object, add the application ID.

```
...
    stub.PostModelOutputs(
      {
         user_app_id: {
           user_id: "me",  // The literal "me" resolves to your user ID.
           app_id: "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
         },
        model_id: 'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7',
        inputs: [{ data: { image: { url: 'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg' } } }], 
      },
...
```

Comment: This is tough. Copied your code exactly and and generated a new PAT for use. Replaced the API key with the PAT and set the `user_id` to `me` (also tried putting the actual user id copied from console) and the `app_id` to the app I created. Yet, I still get the same error.

Comment: @lookininward There existed an issue that has been fixed, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have respected the format to pass the key in your code as such:

```
const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
metadata.set("authorization", "Key {YOUR_CLARIFAI_API_KEY}");
```

Make sure that "Key" is present.

Let me know.

Comment: Yes, I believe I've formatted the pass key correctly: `metadata.set("authorization", "Key xyzKey");`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So looks like Firebase doesn't support custom headers.  This is likely impacting the 'Authorization' header.  At least this is my best guess.  See the comments in the following ticket.

[Firebase hosting custom headers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646417/firebase-hosting-custom-headers-not-working)

---

The following code works for me:

```
{
  const { ClarifaiStub } = require('clarifai-nodejs-grpc');
  const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
  const stub = ClarifaiStub.json();
  const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
  metadata.set("authorization", "Key {APP API KEY}");

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stub.PostModelOutputs(
      {
        model_id: 'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7',
        inputs: [{ data: { image: { url: 'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg' } } }],
      },
      metadata,
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(`ERROR: ${err}`);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    );
  });
}
```

There was a missing `{` although I'm not sure if that is what is reflected in the actual code you are running.  I'm using in this case an APP API Key (when you create an App, there will be an API Key on the Application Details page.

It sounds like you might be using a Personal Access Token instead, which can be used like this:

```
{  
  const { ClarifaiStub } = require('clarifai-nodejs-grpc');
  const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
  const stub = ClarifaiStub.json();
  const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
  metadata.set("authorization", "Key {Personal Access Token}"); // Sounds like you've made the personal access token correctly - go into settings, then authentication, then create one.  Make sure it has proper permissions (I believe all by default).

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stub.PostModelOutputs(
      {
        user_app_id: {
          user_id: "{USER ID}",  // I used my actual ID, I did not put 'me'.  You can find this under your profile.
          app_id: "{APP NAME}" // This is the app ID found in the upper left corner of the app after it is created - not the API Key.  This is generally what you named the app when you created it.
        },
        model_id: 'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7',
        inputs: [{ data: { image: { url: 'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg' } } }],
      },
      metadata,
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(`ERROR: ${err}`);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Make sure to fill out the: {Personal Access Token}, {USER ID} and {APP NAME}.  I used my actual user id (found in the profile), and the app name is not the API Key for the app, but the name in the upper left corner when you're on the Application details page.  This call worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So here's the catch: I'm able to get my original code, and yours as well working when running it in isolation. However, what I need to do is call it from within a Firebase `onRequest` or `onCall` function. When this code gets wrapped by these, the malformed headers and request for authorization are still an issue. We use many other APIs this way so it's puzzling why the Clarifiai API is having these issues. Any suggestions on using it with Firebase?

Comment: Ah, I see @lookininward.  I don't really have any advice - I agree that there shouldn't be an issue.  Do you happen to have a minimum set of code that replicates it using firebase? I'm not familiar with what they are doing, but I can try to take a look.  It sounds like their wrapping might be doing something slightly abnormal that for some reason is breaking our REST - but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: @lookininward I updated the answer; I think firebase might not support wrapping the 'Authorization' header.